# how to create jpql query to get Entity with no associated parent

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a `unidirectional relationship` between an `Employee` and his `Location`.The Location is unaware of Employee.

```
emp1-----------> loc1
emp2------------> loc1
emp3------------> loc3
```

Using JPA, I mapped this as follows

```
@Entity
class Employee{
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   Location location;
}
@Entity
class Location{
   ...
   int roomNumber;
   String aptName;
   String street;
   String city;
}
```

Is it possible to make a `jpql query` to get a list of all `Location objects that have no Employee associated` with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work.

select l from Location l where l not in (select e.location from Employee e)